# Query for student's marks and grades in moodle

Tags: mysql, moodle

I'm trying to get a student's marks and grades with a query but I can't work out joins. It is very complex database. Has anyone done it before?

The query below (tables modified by myself) works for some student but not for others so I need a proper one with original table structure.

Thanks

**MY FAULTY QUERY**

```
SELECT mdl_grade_items.id AS ItemID,
       mdl_course.shortname AS CourseShortname,
       mdl_grade_items.itemname AS ItemName,
       mdl_grade_items.grademax AS ItemGradeMax,
       mdl_grade_items.aggregationcoef AS ItemAggregation,
       mdl_grade_grades.finalgrade AS FinalGrade,
       mdl_user.username AS StudentID,
       mdl_user.id
FROM mdl_grade_items
  INNER JOIN mdl_grade_grades 
    ON mdl_grade_items.id = mdl_grade_grades.itemid
  INNER JOIN mdl_role_assignments 
    ON mdl_grade_grades.userid = mdl_role_assignments.userid 
    AND mdl_grade_items.courseid = mdl_role_assignments.mdlcourseid
  INNER JOIN mdl_course 
    ON mdl_course.id = mdl_grade_items.courseid
  INNER JOIN mdl_user 
    ON mdl_user.id = mdl_role_assignments.userid
WHERE mdl_grade_items.courseid = '2864' 
  AND mdl_user.username = '123456789'
```

Comment: "it does not work": what do you mean? Do you get wrong results? Partial results? No result? An error?

Comment: Can you share the table structure of the tables you are trying to access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify the query if you ignore the enrolment status of the student (perhaps filter   students later if necessary).

Here is an example which will give you all the grades of a user in a course:

```
  SELECT 
  u.id AS userid,
  u.username AS studentid,
  gi.id AS itemid,
  c.shortname AS courseshortname,
  gi.itemname AS itemname,
  gi.grademax AS itemgrademax,
  gi.aggregationcoef AS itemaggregation,
  g.finalgrade AS finalgrade
  FROM mdl_user u
  JOIN mdl_grade_grades g ON g.userid = u.id
  JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON g.itemid =  gi.id
  JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = gi.courseid
  WHERE gi.courseid  = :courseid AND u.username = :username;
```

If that doesn't suit, perhaps you could explain what you are trying to achieve from a non-technical standpoint.